# preventing a process from getting input with C

Tags: c

i have a programs that simulates a shell, i am creating a run in background possibility, when i run another process with FORK -> EXEC, it still sometimes get the input(context switch or smthng) i want to completely block the process from my shell making it exactly like the & operator in linux. i am looking for a solution with signals but cant find any way to do it. 
any suggestions?

```
            if((son = fork())==0){//son process
            getcwd(cur, 1024);
            strcat(cur, "/");
            strcat(cur, tokens_set[0]);
            tokens_set[0] = cur;
            i = execvp(tokens_set[0],tokens_set); //run the command
            if(i == (-1)){
                perror("couldn't find the command: ");
            }
            exit(0);

        }else{ // father process

            printf("and father proccess goes on\n");
        }
```

then the father process goes on, the son process is simply a get input -> print the same program. in my case sometimes the father gets the input and sometimes the son. also when i run with valgrind the son ALWAYS gets the input.

Answer (score 1):

to prevent your child process get the input. I think you can try using `dup2` redirect the stdin to null in your child process.

```
int fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
close(fd);
```

Comment: you mean in the child process?

Comment: @Anton.P Yes, if you don't wanna child process get the input and vice versa.